# Reference book on differential geometry

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Which books should a physics major student read before undertaking a course in differential geometry ? Which books on differential geometry are most suitable for a first reading ?

Comment: "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by John M. Lee from Springer is often considered to be fairly readable because it works out proofs and examples more explicitly than other books of such. We use it right now for the course Differential Geometry consisting of third year bachelor's students in Mathematics and a few from some sort of Physics master (don't know which, nvm). All DG-books are difficult to read in the end because there's always a lot left to the reader but i.m.o. Lee does it best in providing examples and explicit context.